# Gain Xp and level PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php

I have this script for my site and I think I have a problem in the `for` line. If I update my `user_xp_amount` with 256 the script works fine. However, when I update with a higher XP, such as 785, the script is showing me that I have level 1 instead of level 2 with 256xp. Why is this not behaving the way I desire?

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$user_id = 4;
function get_user_xp($user_id, $mysqli) {
   $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_xp_amount FROM users_xp WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
   $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
   return $row['user_xp_amount'];

}

$xp = array(0,256,785,1656,2654);

$my_xp = get_user_xp($user_id, $mysqli); // where 4 is my user id

for($i = 0; $i < count($xp); $i++) {
   if($my_xp == $xp[$i]) {
       echo 'I\'m on level ', ($i+1);
       break;
   }
   else {
       if(isset($xp[$i+1])) {
           if($my_xp > $xp[$i] && $my_xp <= $xp[$i + 1]) {
               echo 'My next level is ', ($i+2), ' and I need ', $xp[$i+1], ' more points for achieving it!';
               break;
            } else {
               echo 'My next level is ', ($i+1), ' and I need ', $xp[$i], ' more points for achieving it!';
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

MySQL DB:

```
user_xp_id Primar   bigint(20) | user_id bigint(20) | user_xp_amount    bigint(20)
```

Comment: Change your loop terminate limit like this : for($i = 0; $i < (count($xp)-1); $i++)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working can be found with some basic debugging:  think through your `for` loop step by step.  If that fails, try something like

```
// snip

for($i = 0; $i < count($xp); $i++) {
    print $i; // show me which step I'm on
    if($my_xp == $xp[$i]) {

    // snip
```

Try that, and the reason will pop out at you.

This is an essential part of debugging:  be careful what you assume.  Your assumption is usually your mistake.

***Only after you go through that exercise*** should you look any further into this answer. (You may not even want to!)

A hint that'll make it easier to code:  you can keep reassigning values until you exit the loop.

```
$xp = array(0,256,785,1656,2654);

$my_xp = 254;

for($i = 0; $i < count($xp); $i++) {

    // if we've looped beyond our xp, exit with last assigned (current) values
    if($my_xp < $xp[$i]) { break; } 

    $my_level = $i;

    // if index + 1 is in range, assign values
    if($i+1<count($xp)) {
        $next_level = $i+1;
        $xp_needed = $xp[$i+1] - $my_xp;

    // if index + 1 is out of range, give default values
    } else {
        $next_level = $i;
        $xp_needed = 0;
    }

}

printf("<div>Current Level: %d (%d xp)</div>" . 
       "<div>Next Level: %d (%d xp)</div>" . 
       "<div>XP Needed: %d</div>",
       $my_level +1, // correct off-by-1 error of index
       $my_xp,

       $next_level +1, // correct off-by-1 error of index
       $xp[$next_level],

       $xp_needed 
);
```